# Определить результат работы кода

Tags: python, python-3.x, bool

На степике есть задача: https://stepik.org/lesson/23899/step/1?adaptive=true&unit=6425

Не могу понять, почему именно такой ответ:

```
true
false
false
true
t or f
false
true
f or t
```

Можно в онлайн режиме увидеть последовательность выполнения? Или ознакомиться на какой ветке, почему именно такие значения печатаются?

Comment: а какой ответ должен быть по твоему?

Answer (score 1):

```
def t():
    print('true')
    return True

def f():
    print('false')
    return False

if t() and f():
    print('t and f')

if f() and t():
    print('f and t')

if t() or f():
    print('t or f')

if f() or t():
    print('f or t')
```

Вот код.

```
if t() and f():
    print('t and f')
```

Вот на этом шаге выводится `true false`. Но так как f = false, то внутренность if не выполняеьтся. Аналогично:

```
if f() and t():
    print('f and t')
```

Но здесь выведется только False. Т.к компилятор не будет проверять второе условие and если первое ложно

А вот в этих блоках

```
if t() or f():
    print('t or f')

if f() or t():
    print('f or t')
```

выполняется и функции и "внутренности", это выводит:

```
true
t or f - в 1-ом блоке
 
false
true
f or t - во втором
```

По той - же причине. Зачем проверять второе условие or, если первое истина